# Alternate arrays merge every third item

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I have two multi-dimensional arrays (but for simplicity sake let's just say they are single dimension) I need to merge them both into a single one, but alternating elements. First array is larger, and I need second array to be merged in every third item.

Just as an example:

```
$array1 = array("Hello", "Bonjour", "Hola", "Ciao", "Привет", "Hallo","Nihao");
$array2 = array("World", "Monde", "Mundo");
```

And I want the final array to look like so

```
["Hello", "Bonjour", "World", "Hola", "Ciao", "Monde", "Привет", "Hallo", "Mundo", "Nihao"]
```

If there are much more items in the first array, then it should just keep adding them, regardless whether second array has any left or not.

How would I do that?

Comment: Post your attempts. What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, the third item of array2 is inserted after the third item of array1, in first and the second are inserted after the second.

Assuming this was a mistake; and $array1 is always large enough; you could use something like this:

```
$i=2; while($v = array_shift($array2))
{
    array_splice($array1, $i, 0, [$v]);
    $i+=3;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like it works. Just remove the ``[`` and ``]`` around ``$v``. It throws an error.

Comment: You're probably running an old PHP version then (not supporting the [] syntax). But you're right; it's optional to create the array if it's just one element; http://php.net/array_splice